# Changing FQDN of nodes in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, networking

I would like to change the DNS of the nodes added to my hadoop cluster.

FOr example, FQDN of a node in my cluster is `hadoop1.dev.com` and I would like to change it to `hadoop1.abc.xyz`

COuld someone suggest me the process to change it without effecting my cluster data.

Answer (score 0):

Update your /etc/hosts file like below, then restart network service to take effect

`x.x.x.x  hadoop1.dev.com  hadoop1.abc.xyz`